# How can I recreate an Altium project given a schematic file and a PCB file?

Tags: altium

Having received a schematic file and PCB file created in Altium, version unknown, I can import both files into Altium 2009 summer. These imports create their own project, therefore I have a PCB project and a schematic project, again they look appropriate and can be edited.

PROBLEM: I have not been able to combine both files into a single project with synchronization between the schematic and PCB so that I can create edits to the PCB via the schematic.

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty project, add the schematics and PCB files manually, compile, done.

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty project and add the schematic and PCB files to it.

You will need to play with project settings a bit to figure out the correct warnings/errors, hierarchical scope, parameters, etc., but these should be evident from deficiencies in the schematics, or new (added/broken) connectivity when pushing to PCB.  Perhaps they were close to your defaults already, or certain features were not used at all (e.g. hierarchical scope settings).

The more outputs you can check against (oh, and you may wish to duplicate outputs with the use of a new OutJob file, if one was not provided), the more certain you can be that settings have been made correctly.  For example, BOM outputs could draw from project settings via substitution strings ('=VariableInProjectSettings').

Or variants; though I suppose that's not a concern (for better or worse) in AD S09. (I forget when variants were introduced, somewhere between v12-14 I think??)  Obviously, any unsupported features will have to be patched over manually; inspect carefully for features driven by PCB design rules and such.